# Neo4j Adding multiple CSV in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a folder of csv files like this - "1232422.csv"

headers:

```
"ID","Name","ScreenName","location","Friends","Followers","Verified","Description","URL","Created_At"
```

there are 1500 files, with the filename having a "follows" relation with the rows of the csv file : `(filename)-[follows]-(csv_row)`

What is the best way to upload all of the data to my neo4j Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the [import config settings](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/load-csv/#query-load-csv-introduction) are correct, you can pass the list of filenames (e.g., `["1232422", "1232423", ...]`) as a `filenames` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) to this query:

```
UNWIND $filenames AS filename
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///"+filename+".csv" AS data
CREATE (f:File {filename:filename})-[:FOLLOWS]->(r:Row)
SET r.csv_row = data
```